# Ansible blockinfile module idempotent?

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x, idempotent

I want to insert some lines in a file using the `blockinfile` module.

```yaml
- name: add some lines
  blockinfile:
    dest: /etc/sysctl.conf
    block: |
      mykey1={{ kernvars['my_value1'] }}
      mykey2={{ kernvars['my_value2'] }}
      mykey3={{ kernvars['my_value3'] }}
```

Is there a way for the module (or a relevant pattern) to check and insert the specific lines only if they are not already there?

Using `ansible 2.0.0.2` on `Ubuntu 16.04.01`.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes. `blockinfile` module is idempotent by default.

In addition to the content you specify, it adds two lines: at the beginning of the block and at the end of the block. On subsequent runs it checks the content between these two markers and if content had not changed, it returns the "ok" status and does not insert it again.

These lines should be inserted to the configuration file as comments, so depending on the exact configuration file format you are using, you can customise the character used for marking the comment with the `marker` argument (by default it's `#`).

If you use multiple `blockinfile` tasks on the same destination file you should additionally add a unique string to each task (also in the `marker` argument), so that Ansible can differentiate between them.

Read more about [`blockinfile`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/blockinfile_module.html) in Ansible documenation.

Comment: Sometimes it's so sad that I can only vote one time for a answer. @techraf Thank you very very much for this clear statement which is missing in the doc.

Comment: @techraf how can we make `blockinfile` idempotent when `marker: false` ?

Answer (score 0):

To add to discussion, if custom a `marker` is used, Ansible adds the line for each run, which is undesired.

You should **ensure** to use `marker_end` and `marker_begin` to keep the task idempotent.

```yaml
- name: blockinfile w begin and end markers
  blockinfile:
    marker_begin: "begin marker"
    marker_end: "end marker"
    dest: /my/file
    block: whatever
```

The placed markers will automagicly have a "#" at the beginning of the line.